# Gscatter for 3 variables

Tags: matlab, classification

I am working on Discriminant Analysis and would like to classify some data using MATLAB. In the example of Fisher's Iris Data as given in MATLAB (visit [www.mathworks.com/products/demos/statistics/classdemo.html](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/statistics/classdemo.html) for details), they consider only the first 2 variables (Sepal Length & Width). I would like to proceed with classification with more features such as Petal Length and Petal Width.

Also, the MATLAB function gscatter seems to take only 2 variables.

`gscatter(meas(:,1), meas(:,2), species,'rgb','osd');`

I would like to include meas(:,3) as well and proceed. Kindly help me. Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with `gscatter` because it only plots 2D data.  If you want to do this for 3D data (as you are including another dimension), consider using [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) to plot the data in 3D.  However, `gscatter` allows you to specify the colour for each group as well as the markers for each point.  We can still do the same with `plot3` but it'll require a bit more work. Spawn a new blank `figure`, use `hold on`, then use a loop to plot all the data belonging to a particular category one at a time with a different colour and marker.

What we should do first is take the categorical data in `species` and assign to each category a unique ID so that we can separate out the correct data to plot.  As such, try doing this:

```
load fisheriris; %// The data that you are referring to
[~,~,id] = unique(species);
colors = 'rgb';
markers = 'osd';

for idx = 1 : 3
    data = meas(id == idx,:);
    plot3(data(:,1), data(:,2), data(:,3), [colors(idx) markers(idx)]);
    hold on;
end
grid; %// Show a grid
```

Let's go through the code slowly.  `load fisheriris` loads in the Fisher Iris data like you have mentioned.  The next line uses [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to go through the `species` array and assigns a unique ID to each string.  We will need this array to separate out the data stored in `meas` for each category so we can plot these on our graph with the different colour and marker.  I declare two string arrays that will store the colours for each marker as well as the markers.  Now, we create a loop that will separate out the data for each unique label, plot this data using `plot3`, then mark each point with the corresponding colour and marker.  You need to use `hold on` so that we can plot more than one set of points in the same graph.  Not doing this will clear the graph every time you call `plot3` and plot only the most recent points added.  As a bonus, we add a `grid` so we can see the graph better.

---

This is what we get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) command is the easiest way to get what you want:

```matlab
scatter3(meas(:,1),meas(:,2),meas(:,3),size,categorical(species))
```

`size` is to plot each circle with a specific size.